# What does ${0%/*} in shell scripts do?

Tags: command-line, sh

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I searched about it without success.

What does exactly the second line do ?:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd ${0%/*} || exit 1
```

I know the first is the shebang, the second tries to change directory but the confusing part is `${0%/*}`.

Can you please explain me that second line?

Comment: As explained by Andrea in an answer, ${0%/*} translates to the directory path prefixed to the script name while invoking it. An alternative is to use the built-in `dirname` command like `$(dirname $0)`

Comment: @alwayslearning: What shell and shell version are you using that `dirname` is built in? It certainly isn't in Bash v4.3.11 which is the default shell in Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, just checked that `dirname` is not a shell built-in.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`${0}` is the first argument of the script, i.e. the script name or path. If you launch your script as `path/to/script.sh`, then `${0}` will be exactly that string: `path/to/script.sh`.

The `%/*` part modifies the value of `${0}`. It means: take all characters until `/` followed by a file name. In the example above, `${0%/*}` will be `path/to`.

You can see it in action on your shell:

```
$ x=path/to/script.sh
$ echo "${x%/*}"
path/to
```

Sh supports many other kinds of "parameter substitution". Here is, for example, how to take the file name instead of the path:

```
$ echo "${x##*/}"
script.sh
```

In general, `%` and `%%` strip suffixes, while `#` and `##` strip prefixes. You can read more about [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: This "|| exit 1" seems to be needless: if it will be noway to change dir $? equals 1.

Comment: It'd be nice to mention the construct is documented as "Remove matching prefix/suffix pattern" in the manual.  Also a nice way to remember which is which is that # is shift 3 (*left* of $), % is shift 5 (*right* of $), at least on the US keyboard.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: the `|| exit 1` _might_ be needed because `cd` might exit with status 2, not 1, on error. However I agree that it's not very useful (usually programs don't care about specific exit statuses). Probably this is part of a larger script?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Surely right. Pretty much the only way it can use useful at all is as part of a larger script. A script which just changes the current directory has no effect, because it only affects the shell running that one script. The parent process never sees it.